# MacBook Pro Ad Hoc and wifi same time

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook, ad-hoc-network, dual-connections

Can I have my MacBook Pro laptop have dual connections, one connecting to an internet wireless access point and one creating an Ad hoc connection to serve this internet connection to others connecting to me on the ad hoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do both at the same time with just the built-in Wi-Fi card, no.  But if you get, say, a third-party USB Wi-Fi adaptor, you can use the USB Wi-Fi adaptor to join the existing Wi-Fi access point, and then use Internet Sharing to enable software access point mode on the built-in adaptor and re-share your other connection. Software access point mode works better with fewer hassles in most cases than ad-hoc (802.11 IBSS) mode.